# How to add Link/URL button into remirror toolbar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [remirror](https://remirror.io/) to build WSYWIG editor.

The requirement is to have an "Link" icon in the toolbar, so that when a user selects text and clicks on that icon, then an options appears to add a hyperlink behind it.

I have found the [LinkExtension](https://remirror.io/docs/extensions/link-extension) in the docs, but I have difficulties figuring out how to add that to the toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1: First you have to include the LinkExtension to your Remirror manager, like documented [here](https://remirror.io/docs/getting-started/create-manager/#add-extensions).
On initialization you can give Remirror some options on how to handle links in the editor. For example:

```
new LinkExtension({ autoLink: true, selectTextOnClick: true }),
```

In this example it tries to automatically parse links (aka put an `<a>`-Tag around your links; `autolink: true`) and selects the complete link text when you click on it (`selectTextOnClick: true`). But there are many other [options](https://github.com/remirror/remirror/blob/main/packages/remirror__extension-link/src/link-extension.ts) (starting at line 95, `LinkOptions`), like automatically open a link on click etc.

2: With that you can use link [commands](https://github.com/remirror/remirror/blob/main/packages/remirror__extension-link/src/link-extension.ts) (starting at line 429 with the `@command` decorator) to add logic to your link button ([Docs](https://remirror.io/docs/getting-started/commands-and-helpers/)).
An (react) Example:

```
// You can access all (!) remirror commands via the useCommands hook.
import { useActive, useCommands } from '@remirror/react'

const LinkButton = () => {
    // active gives you a bunch of booleans to evaluate, if the cursor is
    // currently in a bold, italic or - for our case - link text to control
    // your button.
    const active = useActive()
    const { focus, updateLink } = useCommands()

    return (
        <button
            style={{color: active.link() ? "blue": "black"}}
            onClick={() => {
                updateLink({ href: 'https://www.google.com' })
                focus()
            }}
        >
            <AnyIcon />
        </button>
    )
}
```

You could add this to your toolbar. There are many ways to improve this example.

- Firstly this generates an `<a>`-tag with a fix href to the google website. Clearly we have to find a way to get the selected text and add this as a href.
- Instead of just using `active.link()` for coloring the button text, you could use it to decide in the onClick-function if `updateLink` or `removeLink` (also available via `useCommands`) should be executed.
- Add an actual link icon, maybe from react-icons (`import { MdLink } from 'react-icons/md'`)

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Remirror, but after taking a quick look at the docs, there seems to be all kinds of ToolbarItem-components ex. [ToolbarButtonItem](https://remirror.io/docs/api/react-components.toolbarbuttonitem) that seem right for this use case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @mmatila I have found that one as well, but not a way how to execute the logic now

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that I can add

```
{ type: ComponentItem.ToolbarButton, onClick: () => alert("figure out how to execute logic"), icon: 'link',  }
```

but now I am struggling to figure out how to implement the logic

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that may be very right but can also implement the function. Have you learned the examples from [Showcase - Markdown Editor]? And you only need to replace the `<MarkdownToolbar/>` with something else, just like `<button>Bold</button>`